# Placing a detailed list between images.(CSS/Html)

Tags: html, css, image, list

I am trying to make a detailed list with images on both sides similar to this

image       image
      Alist
image       image

(There are multiple dt's and dd's too)

My problem is that I can get the images aligned right and the list too but the images come before the list like this.
Image     Image

Image     Image

Image     Image

```
  then the list
```

I can get it to work with the images in the list but this gives me errors as images cannot be in a list.
This is part of what im using

```
dl {
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
margin-left:400px; 
margin-right:400px;
}

.floatright {
float: right;
}
.floatleft {
float: left;
 }

<img class="floatleft" src=....
<img class="floatright" src=...
<img class="floatleft" src=....
<img class="floatright" src=...

<dl>
<dt>heading</dt>
<dd>details
</dd>
<dt>heading</dt>
<dd>details etc...
</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: We really need to see what this is supposed to looks like and why can't images be wrapped in a `dd`?

Comment: I'll put up a snippet of the problematic code as soon as i can.

Comment: A design image is really what is required since you may need to revise your HTML structure to resolve the issue. Are the images related to each `dt`?

Comment: Heres a picture of the current page.
http://oi59.tinypic.com/6plspk.jpg
Ideally I want the red text to be between the columns of pictures
(the picture is zoomed out normally the text is in more rows)

Comment: As I said...an image if the required finish result is what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to dl

```
    font-size:25px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
```

and here you can see the output result http://jsfiddle.net/u2peomur/

The width and height of images are set to 50. You can change according to your need. Also change the font-size as you desire

Comment: The way you have done it is how I would like mine to work. However on mine the text still comes out under the images. Is it possible to put pictures/files up here to help show the problem?

Comment: Yeah, just press the print screen button on your keyboard to take a snapshot. Paste it in ms-paint, save it as jpeg.Upload it somewhere and post the link above.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is the dd parts are too long and not going to a new line, instead going under the images. For example on your output result if you change heading to headinggggggg.....It moves it under the images.

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/u2peomur I used word-wrap:break-word in it. Borders are used for testing purposes, you can remove it. Just erase that line border:2px solid green;

Comment: Sorry for being stupid but I can't see where you put the word wrap part.

Comment: Actually it was my mistake, I did not provide you with the correct URL. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/u2peomur/8/ I changed the width to 300px and put word-wrap:break-word thing in dl

Comment: Ah thank you very much for that. Used that and made a slight change for the images I was using and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much. Thanks as well to everyone else who put up answers. Really helpful tips :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this using divs to surround the list, and use inline-block styling.Although inline styling is frowned upon, i felt its easier to demonstrate it like this for simplicity sake, you could always move it to an external css file if you would like to

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:780px; border:red solid 1px;">
        <img src="http://www.html-helper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HTML.jpg" width="150" height="150"/><img src="http://www.html-helper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HTML.jpg" width="150" height="150"/>
        <div style="display:inline-block; border:solid black 1px; vertical-align: top;">
            <dl>
              <dt>Coffee</dt>
              <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
              <dt>Milk</dt>
              <dd>White cold drink</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.html-helper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HTML.jpg" width="150" height="150"/><img src="http://www.html-helper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HTML.jpg" width="150" height="150"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```